# macOS Mojave Safari favicons

Tags: macos, safari

I have a MacBook Pro model A1502.  It's got Mojave version 10.14.4 and Safari 12.1.

I use Top Sites a lot, and they've always had favicons.  Today that changed so that when I go to top sites, it shows the website page instead of the icon.

I've tried (many times) going to **Safari > Preferences > Tabs** and clicked Show website icons, but it hasn't changed.

**What else can I do?**

Looked like this:[image]

Now shows website page thumbnail

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Answer (score 2):

- close Safari
- delete  /Users/Daisy/Library/Safari/Favicon\ Cache (insert your username where appropriate)
- delete /Users/Daisy/Library/Safari/Touch\ Icons\ Cache
- delete /Users/Daisy/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari
- restart Safari

Now watch all blank icons being auto-filled by Safari after a few seconds.

This should work unless the websites that the icons you are missing can no longer be retrieved from the web (website is down, inaccessible etc).

Alternatively, you might try to just delete the offending icon (keep the pointer above it for two seconds to get a close/pin control toggled visible), then open the desired page and drag its favicon to a new window with TopSites again.

---

To find these folders:

1. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in Finder or select Finder Menu > Go > Go to Folder
2. or just open Terminal and type

   - `rm -rv /Users/Daisy/Library/Safari/Favicon\ Cache`

     `rm -rv /Users/Daisy/Library/Safari/Touch\ Icons\ Cache`

     `rm -rv /Users/Daisy/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari`

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I have absolutely no idea where to find all that and how to delete it.  Thank you though.